# JQuery click is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following simple html block:

```
<span class="change_ordering show-list" data-ordering-by="product_list" data-ordering-direction="desc">By list</span>
```

Then, I have following js-code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.show-list').click(function() {
        console.log('qwe');
    });
});
```

When I click on it - nothing happens. But when I paste this js-code to Google Chrome JS console, it works perfectly. JS works fine on my site, I can make other JQuery actions. I also tried to write `$('.change_ordering.show-list')` and `$('span.change_ordering.show-list')` and `$('span.show-list')`, but still no progress. What I'm missing?

**EDIT**: This element is not drowing by ajax. I don't understand why it's duplicate.

Comment: Did you check the error in firebug?

Comment: Fundamentally, that code *will* work. The only reason it wouldn't is if the span doesn't exist in the document as of when you run `$('.show-list')` (e.g., it's added later).

Comment: Your code actually works. See this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/gvp01wLL/ . Any errors that you get in console when you try this

Comment: So by accepting Paresham's answer you show that the span is created after the page has loaded.

Comment: @mplungjan This span is creating with disabled javascript.

Comment: I do not understand your comment

Comment: @mplungjan When I disable JavaScript in browser I still can see this span. It's not creating by ajax.

Comment: Then your original code should have worked too

Comment: @mplungjan That is the point. It works only if I will write `$(document).on("click",".show-list",function(){})`.

Comment: Which is called event delegation and is only needed when the span is not available (with that class) at document.ready time

Comment: @mplungjan Strange. But thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please apply click using following way

```
$(document).on("click",".show-list",function(){})
```

It will work

Comment: Explain please why it is different and why it'd work.

Comment: It works for dynamic appending of dom elements also

Comment: Miracle, it works for me. I have no idea why, but thanks a lot!

Comment: @pareshm I *do* know, but since this is *your* answer, *you* are the one who should explain it :)